# Terminal Window in Windows Using Python

Tags: python, window, terminal

I want to create a window like terminal window or like command prompt for my application using python in windows. I have searched in internet and found some programs. But Its all working in linux and unix machine. But its not working in windows. Because these programs requires modules like (vte,termios). Its not available for windows.

Answer (score 0):

[Bruce](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/bruce) has one. check out and browse the source; I guess [`bruce/interpreter.py`](http://code.google.com/p/bruce-tpt/source/browse/trunk/bruce/interpreter.py) will be interesting.

Comment: Hi Flying Sheep. Pls explain what this code will do. I am very new to python. how it ll helpful for me ???

Comment: in this case it’s probably difficult for you to adapt it, as it’s an implementation of a rudimentary python shell. if you want a unix shell, i can only tell you that the only project implementing this that i know of (Console2) somehow wraps the windows cmd.exe, which seems very complicated to pull off…